# lemmatization issue using Spacy in pandas Series and Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, spacy

I am working on [text data](https://www.kaggle.com/crowdflower/twitter-airline-sentiment) having shape of (14640,16) using Pandas and Spacy for preprocessing but having issue in getting lemmetized form of text. Moreover, if I work with pandas series (i.e dataframe with one column) which contain only text column there are different issue with that also.

Code: (Dataframe)

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
df['parsed_tweets'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: nlp(x))
df[:3]
```

Result:
[image: Result]

After this I iterate over the column with parsed_tweets to get lemmetized data but get the error.

Code:

```
for token in df['parsed_tweets']:
  print(token.lemma_)
```

Error:
[image: Error]

Code: (Pandas Series)

```
df1['tweets'] = df['text']

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
for text in nlp.pipe(iter(df1), batch_size = 1000, n_threads=-1):
  print(text)
```

Error:
[image: Error]

Can someone help me with the errors? I tried other stackoverflow solution but can't get doc object of Spacy to iterate over it and get tokens and lemmetized tokens.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#you can directly get your lemmatized token by running list comprehension in your lambda function  

df['parsed_tweets'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: [y.lemma_ for y in  nlp(x)])
```

[image]

```
print(type(df['parsed_tweets'][0]))
#op
spacy.tokens.doc.Doc


for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    for word in df['parsed_tweets'][i]:
        print(word.lemma_)
#op
play
football
i
be
work
hard
```

Comment: Can you tell me what I was doing wrong with my code? I think I was also trying to do the same.

Comment: your parsed_tweet column contain tuple of token, and you are using for token in df['parsed_tweet'] which is taking tuple as row value, and not word token ...

Comment: Is there any way to convert tuple to list if that is the issue to get tokens in Spacy as i have tried to change tuple column to list column using `list(tuple)` but it also doesn't work? Does Spacy only take list as input for tokens?

Comment: type of each row element in parsed_tweets columns is spacy.tokens.doc.Doc, so you have to iterate here as well. print(type(df['parsed_tweets'][0]))

Comment: I tried using your code but it gives me this error. 

`<ipython-input-31-06f6cc0f2282> in <module>()`
      `3 for i in range(df.shape[0]):`
      `4     for word in df['parsed_tweets'][i]:`
`----> 5         print(word.lemma_)`

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'lemma_'`

Comment: what is type for  df['parsed_tweet'][0], try to run type(df['parsed_tweets'][0]), if 
 it not spacy.tokens.doc.Doc than it will throw error